# Py_EndInterpreter hangs after DECREF

Tags: python-3.x, embedding, cpython

I am embedding Python36 into my C++ adapter. Adapter loads python plugins and for each plugin loaded, creates new sub-interpreter. However, I am failing even with the simpliest example.

```cpp
Py_Initialize();
PyEval_InitThreads();

PyThreadState * pThreadState = Py_NewInterpreter();
assert(pThreadState == PyThreadState_GET());

PyObject * obj = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
Py_DECREF(obj); // Py_EndInterpreter hangs if this is executed

Py_EndInterpreter(pThreadState);
```

Calling `Py_DECREF` hangs `Py_EndInterpreter` call. Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try acquiring the GIL beforehand using `PyGILState_Ensure()`

Comment: I moved `Py_Initialize` and `Py_Finalize` to `DllMain` and now it seems working. But still I don't understand why.